# How can I extend the CustCustomerService and SalesLineService standard service?

Tags: web-services, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, aif

I'd like to add an extra field to the AX 2012 standard service "CustCustomerService" and "SalesLineService".

I think I have just to extend the query, that was used to create this service. But I have no idea how to find this queries.

Comment: Do you have access to customer source?

Comment: No, but I hope next month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the fields to the class `AxCustTable` and `AxSalesLine` should do it.

The queries are named `AxdCustomer` and `AxdSalesOrder`. You do not need to add them there, as the fields are dynamically added at run time.

Comment: What I'm trying is:  1. I added a field to the DirPartyPostalAddressView (This view ist used in the AxCustTable query)  2. Update the CustCustomerService including recreating the classes.  3. The new Field is in the classes AxDirPartyPostalAddressView and CustCustomer_DirPartyPostalAddressView  4. Deactivate/Activate the Service in AX.  5. Update the Service in my C# program...  The new Field isn't there.  Where could I've lost it?

Comment: The restart of the AOS hasn't fixed the problem. :(

Comment: Review your changes to `AxCustTable` to verify that your new field implementation is similar to other fields.

Comment: All classes were OK. But I had to update the Service with the Form AifService. This form was in AX 2009 in the menu in AX 2012 it is only in the AOT.